# How do I force Chrome Postman to return application/xml instead of application/octect-stream

Tags: java, xml, rest, google-chrome-devtools

I am using google chrome plugin Postman for testing some restful web services.  Some of my webservices have a produces annotation that has several types defined. Each time I run one of my services though, it seems postman's results are determined to always return in octect-stream form.  Is there a way to force postman (or potentially my service) to return application/xml results?  I would prefer not to change the annotation but will if thats my only choice.

My service definition -

```
@GET
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, 
"application/x-javascript", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM } )
@Path( "/getCustomers/" )
public Response getCustomers
```

My postman call is just a GET call with no parameters on the header like this:

```
http://myserver:8080/test/getCustomers
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are returning a correct value (`application/xml`) in the `Content-Type` header? MIME will default to `octect-stream` if browser can't recognise type of content itself.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Maybe your default response type is **octect-stream**

Use the below http headers in POSTMAN

> Accept: application/xml

Do the server validations based on Accept headers.

Comment: This fixed it, I just added a header of Accept with a value of application/xml and resent it.  Returned result came back as xml,Thanks!